# Prove the limit of the function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let f be the function whose domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$ deﬁned by
$f(x) = x$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

(a) Prove $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$. (b) Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume $a = 0$.

(b) Prove $\lim_{x→a} f(x)$ does not exist.

Can someone help me to figure it out? I appreciated it!

Comment: In b) you mean a not equal to 0, right??

Comment: yes! sorry for not typing it in.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please refer to this tutorial for formatting problems using MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given the function:

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x &&: x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
&0 &&: x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

From the definition of limit of a single-variable function, we want to prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \ \exists \delta>0 $ such that $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \ \implies \ |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$; in this particular case, $x_0 = L = 0$. The strategy for these types of limit proofs is to find some function $\delta(\varepsilon)$ which satisfies the aforementioned statement we wish to prove. This method allows us to find an explicit $\delta$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

Suppose in the first case that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(x) = x$. Furthermore, if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then we have $f(x) = 0$. From the definition of the given function, it is clear that $|f(x)| \leq |x|$. Observe that if we fix $\delta = \varepsilon$, we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$|f(x)| \leq |x| < \delta = \varepsilon$$

Thus the conditional statement $0 < |x| < \delta \ \implies \ |f(x)| < \varepsilon$ holds.

For the second part, suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$. We want to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ D.N.E. Suppose to the contrary that the limit does exist and is equal to $\gamma$. Then from the definition of limit, we have:

$$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \ \implies \ |f(x)-\gamma|< \varepsilon $$

Now, suppose that $x \notin \mathbb{Q} \ \implies \ f(x) = 0$. Then on the right-hand side of the implication, we have $|\gamma| < \varepsilon$. But $|\gamma|$ is a fixed constant, and the definition of limit requires that the implication hold **for all** $\varepsilon > 0$. Thus by contradiction, the limit as $x \rightarrow a$ does not exist. QED

Comment: very clear explanation! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

How to prove a limit exists (or does not)

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(a) = L$

The definition of limits.

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0: |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

Learn this, love this.

to the problem at hand

$|f(x)| \le |x|$ for all $x.$

If $\delta < \epsilon$

$|x|<\delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon$

If $a\ne 0$
Choose $\epsilon < a/2$

In any neighborhood of $a$, there exists both a rational $x$ and an irrational $x$.  For one $f(x) = 0$ and the other $f(x) > 2\epsilon$

There is no $L$ such that $|f(x) -L| <\epsilon$

Comment: $|f(x)|\leqslant |x|$.

Comment: Sorry， I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What don't you understand.  The definition of the limit? or that we can find a $\delta$ that satisfies the definition in one case, and cannot in the other?